# File access denied trying to create on Network shared folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a file on a local shared folder and write the contents of the file to the document created on shared local folder from my c# Webservice, I get access denied, server could not process this request. I am since wondering what the worry might be. My Code is looking like this

```
private void SaveFiletoLocalDisk()
{
    string mypath = Server.MapPath("~/Files");
    string filedocx = "ExpenseApprovalMemo2.docx";
    string mymainDocumentPath = Path.Combine(mypath, filedocx);

    string dateToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    Random r = new Random();
    string snum = Convert.ToString(r.Next(5, 200));
    string originFile = mymainDocumentPath;
    string destinationFile = @"\\**.**.**.**\EmemoFailover\";
    string FileRef = dateToday + snum;
    string finalOutputFile = Convert.ToString(FileRef) + ".docx";

    try
    {
        FileStream SW1;
        FileIOPermission myPerm = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, destinationFile + finalOutputFile);
        myPerm.Assert();
        SW1 = File.Create(destinationFile + finalOutputFile);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And I am still getting the Error. Please I would like to know why This is so.

Edit

The Error is as given below :

[image]

Comment: Have you writing rights on the target ?

Comment: @Cid, yes I do.

Comment: Does it require to enter a login/password when you manually navigate to `\\**.**.**.**` ?

Comment: @Cid, No. it does not,

Comment: Which specific line causes the Access Denied error?

Comment: @Marin, Hi, Please See edits. Does not show the particular Line

Comment: Try replacing ip with domain.

Comment: "Does not show the particular Line"...if you weren't needlessly catching and re-throwing the exception, it would. Don't use try/catch blocks unless you're going log the error and hide it from the user, and allow the program to continue. `catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }` is pointless, it wastes CPU (because catching and throwing is comparatively expensive to do), it obscures the source of the error, and it doesn't stop the program from crashing. It's an anti-pattern. I'm not sure where you got the idea to write it like that.

Comment: P.S. If this code is running in a "webservice" as you state (although it looks like a Windows Forms application in reality - does it make a call to a webservice or something??), then remember it may not be running with the same user account permissions as you have got personally. Check what account the service actually runs as and what permissions that account has.

Comment: @Berkay, says could not find file

Comment: So, your path is wrong. @Ukrainian

Comment: @Adyson, Well i am running the Webservice from K2 Smartforms Application , thats why it looks like winform . Do you say i remove the try catch exception

Comment: Your try/catch does not do anything useful, so you can remove it. And you should then get a better stack trace with the exact line number.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your web application is trying to write to a UNC path - quite possibly on a different server.

By default it will be running with a built in account. These docs have more info - they refer to IIS 7, but I believe it is still valid in higher versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

Try finding the application pool that your application is running under, and edit the `Application Identity` in the Advanced settings. Temporarily set the identity to `Custom` using your own network credentials and see if it works.

If this resolves your problem, you should create a new Network Account to run the application under, with just the permissions to the folder that it needs

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the Visual Studio as administrator. if its a process or exe, then try running the process or exe as administrator. Otherwise your best bet is to do impersonation.

Otherwise you can try Right click on the network folder and select properties. Then uncheck the read-only option. After clicking OK, it should start working.